# Using constants across namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, constants

I'm working with namespaces and PHP 5.3 on my framework project.  I have the main `App` class and an `Autoloader` class.  In the `App` class, I set up a few environment variables:

```
public static function setupEnv()
        {
            $os = 'UNIX';
            if (stristr(PHP_OS,'WIN'))
            {
                $os = 'WIN';
            }

            if (!defined('DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR'))
            {
                define('DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR',($os == 'UNIX') ? '/' : '\\');

            }
            define('DS', \DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

            if (!defined('PATH_SEPARATOR'))
            {
                define('PATH_SEPARATOR', ($os == 'UNIX') ? ':' : ';');
            }
            define('PS', \PATH_SEPARATOR);

            if (!defined('APP_PATH'))
            {
                define('APP_PATH', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
                define('AP', APP_PATH);
            }
        }
```

The constants get defined properly, both `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` and `DS` and if I echo them here they work just fine.  The namespace for this is Feather\App.  In the `Autoloader` class, I use the `DS` constant and it works fine just.  The `Autoloader` class is in the same Feather\App namespace.

I am running PHPUnit, and created this test - `setupEnv()` is called in the `setUp()` function of PHPUnit:

```
public function testAutoloadFunction()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . DS.'Components'.DS.'Collections'.DS.'Collection.php',
            \Feather\App\Autoloader::Autoload('\\Feather\\Components\\Collections\\Collection')
        );
    }
```

This fails the test, even though the path comes back correctly.  It says:

`Use of undefined constant DS - assumed 'DS'`

So that's a lot of backstory to get to my question - why is that an error?  I thought, OK, maybe I need to reference \Feather\App\DS, but that throws this:

`PHP Fatal error: Undefined constant 'Feather\App\DS' in /web/Feather/Tests/AutoloaderTest.php`

I thought that constants were defined in the global scope, so shouldn't this work?  If not, how do I make this work so that PHPUnit is happy?  If I put `use Feather\App` at the top, it still fails with the same `assumed 'DS'` error.

Can someone explain this?  The PHP documentation has been thus far unhelpful!

Comment: One of your observations must be wrong. The constants were undefined, thus the `setupEnv()` method and/or the `App` class were not run before the unittest.

Comment: If I attempt to echo `DS` before the `setupEnv()` command, it's empty/undefined.  If I echo it after `setupEnv()`, it's defined.  This isn't a constant being defined elsewhere.  So the fact that the unit test uses the proper value for `DS`, I would argue otherwise.

Comment: Add `assert('defined("DS")');` throughout that unittest method to find out more. And add `print "setupEnv"` to the init function for debugging.

Comment: Interesting, I just tested on a Windows workstation with WAMP and it works ... but on my Linux workstation, it fails.  I will do some more digging on that tonight.

Comment: OK - I have no idea what I did, but it's working now.  I think the issue is that I wasn't checking `if (!defined('DS'))` and when the `setUp()` function ran on subsequent tests, it caused issues.  That's my best guess.  The code is working now!

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and got the tests to run with the following steps:

1. Marking the tests with an `@runInSeparateProcess` annotation
2. Overriding `run()` in the test class like so:

   public function run(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult $result = NULL) {
   $this->setPreserveGlobalState(false);
   return parent::run($result);
   }
3. Putting the `require_once()` that causes the constant to be defined in the test file into `setUp()`:

   public function setUp() {
   require_once **DIR**.'/SetUpEnv.php';
   }

This may not be an ideal workaround, but it is no doubt better than no workaround at all.

I scraped bits and pieces (or maybe the whole thing) from other answers on StackOverflow and/or elsewhere, but it has been awhile, so apologies to the sources I'm not citing here.